# CTCallCenter callEventHandler is never called

Tags: ios, iphone, core-telephony, ios-9-beta3

I try to use CTCallCenter to receive incoming call from iPhone. While application is active I call to device and nothing happens callEventHandler is not invoked.

What can be a reason?

I use IOS9.0 beta3 installed on iPhone 5 and XCode7.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call)
{
    if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");
        [self ShowMessage:@"Call has been disconnected"];
    }
    else if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
        [self ShowMessage:@"Call has just been connected"];
    }
    else if(call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming)
    {
        NSLog(@"Call is incoming");
        [self ShowMessage:@"Call is incoming"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"None of the conditions");
        [self ShowMessage:@"None of the conditions"];
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I've solved it, the CTCallCenter *callCenter should be defined as property in ViewController:

Comment: I'm seeing that callEventHandler is not called on iOS 9.3.5.